# Web-kit css div shadow: is it possible to put it onto div with pure css or images are needed?

Tags: javascript, css, html, webkit

So what I need is simple: user presses something, user sees a shadow effect on new div (div centered window) on top of all page (with 1/4 size for example) alike  [image: chrome set up page]

Is it possible with some pure web-kit css art? Or javascript+images combination is needed? And how to do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this quote:

> Web-kit css div shadow: is it possible
>   to put it onto div with pure css

and this one:

> user sees a shadow effect on new div

It seems as though you're asking if it's possible to create the "shadow" effect around the inner `div` using CSS.

Chrome's settings page is using [CSS3's `box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) to do this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 80px #505050;
```

`box-shadow` works in these browsers: http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow

and the cross-browser CSS is:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 80px #505050;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 80px #505050;
box-shadow: 0 5px 80px #505050;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XHAbV/

If you need it to work in older versions of IE, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to emulate the `box-shadow` in those browsers.

If you're after the JavaScript side of how to do this (a modal window), the other answer covers it quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for can be called a modal window. It can be done using [CSS3 properties](http://www.net-kit.com/10-css3-lightbox-alternatives/), but it is supported only in IE9+, Firefox 4, Chrome, and Opera.

For a cross-browser solution, you should look at javascript scripts which can render the same effect. There are many popular packages like [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/), [ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/), [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), [FaceBox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/), etc.

If you are using ASP.NET, there is the ModalPopupExtender in the [AJAXToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/), which will give you the effect.

Answer (score 2):

You need two things a div for your dialog box with box-shadow and another div that lies behind your dialog box with an opacity of 50% or so. This can be done with some css in most every browser including ie. Read this article on how to get box-shadow work in all browser: http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/

so your html will look like this:

```
<div class="overlay"/>
<div class="dialogbox">someContent</div>
```

and your css:

```
.overlay {
     position:absolute; 
     height: 100%; 
     width: 100%;
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  opacity: 0.5;
}
.dialogbox{ 
    width: 200px; 
    height: 150px; 
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
```

}